# What is the Search Type Of android SearchView?

Tags: android, searchview

In Android SearchView widget that provides a UI.
It will search query and submit a request to a search provider.

There are different type of search query Provided by Collections like BinarySearch...

**What kind of Search query performed by Android Widget SearchView.?**

(BinarySearch Or LinerSearch Or anything else...)

Comment: looking at [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java), it finally raises an intent with action as ACTION_SEARCH. If only we can figure out how android handles such intents.

Comment: @AmitBarjatya I think that [this section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity) of the documentation may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is up to the app developer to search the data and to provide the results to the search widget. The search widget provides a framework for the app to perform its searches but does not search the data directly. From [Creating a Search Interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchingYourData):

> **Searching your data**
>
> The process of storing and searching your data is unique to your application. You can store and search your data in many ways, but this guide does not show you how to store your data and search it. Storing and searching your data is something you should carefully consider in terms of your needs and your data format.

So you can search your data in the way that makes the most sense for how the data is stored and organized.

Answer (score 5):

If you ask about `android.widget.SearchView`, you can implement interface `android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and do anything you want inside it.

For example, let's create `OnQueryTextListener` as Activity part:

```
public class MyActivity implements OnQueryTextListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        ...

        SearchView s=new SearchView(this);
        s.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        s.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        s.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        s.setOnQueryTextListener(this);  // <--- this sets listener

        ...

    }
```

And now two methods what you have to implement:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){
        return false;  // <--- you can leave it empty!
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
        if(!query.isEmpty()){
            do_something_on_user_post();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I know How To Implement .. I just Wanted To Know type Of Search Query.

Answer (score 4):

An Android "**Widget**" is  to perform the search but does not search the data directly
you implement your own search algorithm